# Trigger.io build server seems to be stuck on our app, never gets past "starting new build" step

Tags: ios, trigger.io

Below is the debug log- Note that the debug output stops at this point, even waiting an hour no additional debug output is generated.

FYI, we're signed up for the "Go Big" plan.

[INFO] Starting new HTTPS connection (1): trigger.io
[INFO] Forge tools running at version 3.3.82
[DEBUG] Forge build tools version: 3.3.82
[DEBUG] main: {"server": "https://trigger.io/api/"}
[DEBUG] port: 38394
[DEBUG] GET https://trigger.io/api/v1/app/03e9a8b2cc8e11e2903e12313d00dc45/should_fetch_core_instructions
[DEBUG] Checking API response for success or error
[DEBUG] Invalidated whole cache
[DEBUG] configuration is identical to last run
[DEBUG] POST https://trigger.io/api/v1/reload/buildevent/create
[DEBUG] Checking API response for success or error
[INFO] Your app configuration has changed since your last build of this platform, performing a remote build of your app. Once this is downloaded future builds will be faster.
[INFO] Starting new build
[INFO] This could take a while, but will only happen again if you modify config.json
[DEBUG] POST https://trigger.io/api/v1/app/03e9a8b2cc8e11e2903e12313d00dc45/build
[DEBUG] Checking API response for success or error
[DEBUG] build 45538 is pending...
[DEBUG] POST https://trigger.io/api/v1/app/03e9a8b2cc8e11e2903e12313d00dc45/build
[DEBUG] Checking API response for success or error
[DEBUG] build 45538 is working...
[DEBUG] POST https://trigger.io/api/v1/app/03e9a8b2cc8e11e2903e12313d00dc45/build
[DEBUG] Checking API response for success or error
[DEBUG] build 45538 is working...
[DEBUG] POST https://trigger.io/api/v1/app/03e9a8b2cc8e11e2903e12313d00dc45/build
[DEBUG] Checking API response for success or error
[DEBUG] build 45538 is working...
[DEBUG] POST https://trigger.io/api/v1/app/03e9a8b2cc8e11e2903e12313d00dc45/build
[DEBUG] Checking API response for success or error
[DEBUG] build 45538 is working...
[DEBUG] POST https://trigger.io/api/v1/app/03e9a8b2cc8e11e2903e12313d00dc45/build
[DEBUG] Checking API response for success or error
[DEBUG] build 45538 is working...
[DEBUG] POST https://trigger.io/api/v1/app/03e9a8b2cc8e11e2903e12313d00dc45/build
[DEBUG] Checking API response for success or error
[DEBUG] build 45538 is working...
[DEBUG] POST https://trigger.io/api/v1/app/03e9a8b2cc8e11e2903e12313d00dc45/build
[DEBUG] Checking API response for success or error

Comment: I love how trigger.io asks me to post to stackoverflow, where my posts are summarily downvoted, draining away my karma :-)

Comment: As a "Go Big" customer you most certainly do qualify for support by an actual breathing human, have you contacted support@trigger.io?

Comment: @drcode how did you fixed it?